# Which adverb fits here? "Dabei" und "gleichzeitig"

Tags: adverb

Question: Dieser Roman liest sich sehr leicht ____________ kann man sogar Musik hören.

Here the correct answer is 'dabei'.
But I don't see any point why 'gleichzeitig' can't fit here.... At the same time can a person hear Musik..?

Comment: Very, very strictly speaking, both *dabei* and *gleichzeitig* are wrong. "... liest sich sehr leicht ..." describes a *characteristic* of a book - Not any activity that can be done simultaneously to listening to music.

Answer (score 2):

The two variations you offer here are

> Dieser Roman liest sich sehr leicht. Dabei kann man sogar Musik hören.
>
> Dieser Roman liest sich sehr leicht. Gleichzeitig kann man sogar Musik hören.

Technically you can put in here both, *dabei* und *gleichzeitig*, without a mistake in terms of actual grammar.

But there are problems related to style.

If you use *gleichzeitig*, the reader would have to silently interpolate something like

> Dieser Roman liest sich sehr leicht. Gleichzeitig **- also beim Lesen des Romans -** kann man sogar Musik hören.

Which leads us to an explanation why actually **both sentences sound a little bit odd** to the German ear. Both *dabei* and *gleichzeitig* should actually refer to an activity (e.g. *lesen*), not an object (*Roman*), because you can do something **at the same time as another activity**, but not "at the same time as an object".

So, more common would be a sentence like

> Dieser Roman ist leicht zu lesen. Dabei kann man sogar Musik hören.

Here, the *dabei* more clearly refers to *lesen*, which is more in the area of what would usually be expected.